# Print out a selected number of a string problem

Tags: c, arrays, string

The exercise says "Make a function with two parameters a string (s) and an integer(n). The function then will return the first n characters. That's what I did, but I'm getting a compiler error "[Warning] passing arg 1 of `symbolse' makes pointer from integer without a cast". I've tried to do some changes, to override this error but then I don't get  the result I want or the program crashes.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 void symbolse(char s[50],int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%c ",s[i]);


 }

main(){
   int m;
   char a[50];
   printf("Give integer: ");
   scanf("%d",&m);
   printf("Give string: ");
   a[50]=getchar();
   symbolse(a[50],m);

   system("pause");


 }
```

Ex. The user gives m=3 and a[50]=House . The program should print Hou .

Comment: Please, stop learning from wherever is teaching you to use `system("pause")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is with `a[50]=getchar()`. This reads one character into the 50-th position in your buffer (which by the way is out of `a`'s bounds). Trying using `scanf` instead.

`symbolse(a[50],m)` is also wrong. I'll let you figure out what the problem is.

One further hint is to print out the values of your input variables to ensure that you've read them correctly.

Comment: I changed the getchar to  scanf("%c",&a[50]) and the symbolse(a,m). The program compiles but after I give the string it crashes.

Comment: @captain, `&a[50]` is the address of the 51st element in the array, and you have only declared 50 (arrays are zero-based). Also, you probably want to give the address of the *first* element, which is `&a[0]`.

Comment: `&a[50]` points to the memory area *after* the end of your array.

Comment: @dreamlax problem solved, I should have used scanf("%c",&a[0]) I had the impression that in the scanf I should also put the size of the array not where it begins. Thanks.

Comment: and `&a[0]` is equivalent to `a` (with the latter being shorter), btw ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
symbolse(a,m);
```

instead of

```
symbolse(a[50],m);
```

For you want to pass the array (pointer to array, in fact), not its 51st (unexistent) element.

(And the problem pointed by aix also exists, but it's not the one that breaks your compile).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
void symbolse(char s[50],int n){

int i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)

printf("%c ",s[i]);


}

main(){

  int m;

  char a[50];

  printf("Give integer: ");

  scanf("%d",&m);

  printf("Give string: ");

  fgets(a,sizeof(a),strin); /* get chars from stdin */

  symbolse(a,m); /* Call the function giving array's base address */

  system("pause");


}
```

Comment: I get some compiler erros and we haven't learned fgets yet so I don't think that this should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `a[50]=getchar();` because getchar only takes a single char.

Use `scanf("%s",a);` inplace of `a[50]=getchar();`